# JSON Schema for array of nullable doubles

Tags: c#, json, schema, jsonschema

I'm using JSON schema to generate `C#` business objects.

One of my objects contain a property with a list of nullable doubles.

```
IList<double?> List { get; }
```

And I'd like to implement this via schema.

Usually to make this possible I'm using such structure:

```
"type": "number",
"required": false
```

But this doesn't work for array

```
"Values": {
     "type": "array",
     "items": {
         "required": false,
         "type": "number"
     }
}
```

This generated `IList<double>` property.

Tried to find some information on official schema [site](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html). It's quite poor site..

Is there any way to implement such structure without creating a new data type?

**UPD.1**
I'm using [jsonclassgenerator](https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/) generator for `C#` code. It is impossible to migrate another tool...

**UPD.2**

```
"MyType": {
        "id": "MyType",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Values": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "required": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Generated class:

```
public partial class MyType
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public IList<double> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see an obvious way to generate a class from a schema, only from some example JSON. Can you add some info about how you're using this tool?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to separate your question in two problems:

1. How to express a `jsonschema` that contains an array of numbers or
   null values.
2. How to create types from `jsonschema` definitions.

Q1 can be solved in several ways. I would suggest to use and `oneOf` clause this way:

```
"MyType" : {
    "id" : "MyType",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "Values" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "oneOf" : [{
                        "type" : "number"
                    }, {
                        "type" : "null"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Q2 has not relation to `jsonschema` and depends on custom conventions or implementations. For `jsonschema` an `IList` and an `array` are the same thing.

I would suggest you to use more general types in your deserialized structures, and just convert to `IList` when needed.